# How can we achieve table filtering and Sorting with pagination in vue js

Tags: vue.js

I am new in vue js.
How can we achieve table filtering and Sorting with pagination in vue js.??

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please share some code so we can better help you with this question. Check this out for more information on how to write good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vuetify you can use the data table component: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables